# Table view registering - UINib Argument labels '(nibName:, Bundle:)' do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Trying to add a custom cell to my project, the following code returns the error `UINib Argument labels '(nibName:, Bundle:)' do not match any available overloads` at the register line.

Xcode 9 beta 6

```
@IBOutlet var MTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    MTableView.delegate = self as? UITableViewDelegate
    messageTableView.dataSource = self

    MTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MCell", Bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mixed uppercase and lowercase. In Swift, all function arguments start with a **lowercase letter**. Change

```
UINib(nibName: "MCell", Bundle: nil)
```

to

```
UINib(nibName: "MCell", bundle: nil)
```

Comment: That was it ! looking 1 hour was still not seeing it... Thank you and sorry for the stupid question

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use generics to avoid such mistakes.

```
extension UITableView {
  func registerNib<T: UITableViewCell> (_ type: T.Type) {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: T.className, bundle: nil)
    self.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: T.className)
  }
 }
```

Now you can simply register cells as follows:

```
self.tableView.registerNib(MyInfoViewCell.self)
```

I use this extension https://github.com/sanjaymhj/SwiftyStarters/blob/master/Extensions/UIView%2BExtension.swift to avoid these kind of errors. You can see the usecase for registering cell and dequeuing in readme https://github.com/sanjaymhj/SwiftyStarters/blob/master/README.md#extensions